# Trying to parameterize a section of the URI Path in karate

Tags: karate, url-parameters, web-api-testing

This is my first time trying out Karate.

I have a URI - Eq -https://xxxx.xxx.com:8643/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxxxx/{equipmentNumber}/xxxx

I want to parametrize only equipmentNumber in this path. How do I do it?.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
* def equipmentNumber = 'foo'
* url 'https://xxxx.xxx.com:8643/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxxxx'
* path equipmentNumber, 'xxxx'
```

Or:

```
* url 'https://xxxx.xxx.com:8643/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xxxxx/' + equipmentNumber + '/xxxx'
```

There are many options. Read the docs.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I still dont understand how you are parametrizing it?. Also what docs are you talking about can you please share the link?.

Comment: @Sushma here are the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#url

Comment: Disregard my previous question, was able to make it work!. Thanks Peter!.